# Real (de realeza) y real (de realidad)

Tags: etimología, historia

El adjetivo "real" tiene dos acepciones distintas: puede referirse a lo relativo al rey ("realeza"), como en "camino real" o "real Academia Española"; o a lo que tiene existencia concreta,  (en la "realidad").

¿Esto es pura coincidencia, o hay un origen común?

Dicho de otra manera: ¿Las palabras "realeza" y "realidad" están conectadas etimológicamente?

Comment: "Real" también es lo relativo al _reo_.

Comment: también tiene que ver con el mus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es coincidencia (debido a la similitud de las raíces latinas y su evolución al castellano). *Real*, con esas dos acepciones proviene de dos adjetivos distintos que confluyen en castellano.

De acuerdo a etimologías de Chile ([entrada de realeza](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?realeza#:%7E:text=Informaci%C3%B3n%20sobre%20REALEZA-,REALEZA,rey%2C%20real%20y%20tambi%C3%A9n%20pereza.))

> la palabra **realeza** (grandiosidad propia de un monarca) viene del sufijo *-eza* (cualidad) sobre la palabra "real", la cual viene del latín *regalis* = "relativo al rey"

En los enlaces de esa entrada se puede profundizar más sobre la etimología de "rey" y "real".

"Rey" viene de *rex, regis* que tiene la misma raíz indoeuropea que *reg* (derecho, conducir en línea recta - o sea, gobernar).

En la entrada de [real](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?real) se explica que

> La palabra **real** en relación al rey o monarca viene del latín *regalis*. *Regalis* estó formada de la base **reg**, la cual se refiere al lado derecho del cuerpo.

> La palabra *real* con la semántica de verdadero proviene del latín, pero de otra palabra, *res* (cosa).

y se explica que en **real** se da una homoninia, ya que provienen de dos adjetivos latinos distintos que confluyen en castellano: el primero de **regalis**, "real, regio" (derivado de rex, regis - rey) y segundo de **realis** (real, verdadero - literalmente "relativo a las cosas" porque viene de **res** "cosas").

Así que la clave de esa homonimia está en la similitud entre "re**g**alis" (relativo al rey) y "realis" (relativo a las cosas).